# Использование функции throttle

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста как правильно использовать функцию throttle, чтобы уменьшить количество вызовов функции обновления страницы. Пытался сделать что-то типа *window.onresize = throttle(updateSize, 300);* не помогло.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    svgDoc = document.getElementById("AutoId").contentDocument;
    var timer = setInterval(anim, 100);
    var timerPost = setInterval(setPost, 100);
    initClick();
 updateSize();
}

window.onresize = updateSize;

function updateSize() {
    vpW = document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0].clientWidth;
    vpH = document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0].clientHeight;
    //imgW = document.getElementsByClassName('box content')[0].clientWidth;
    //imgH = document.getElementsByClassName('box content')[0].clientHeight;
    imgW = 1088;
    imgH = 1088;
    //alert(vpW + ':' + vpH + ' = ' + vpW/vpH + '      ' + imgW + ':' + imgH + ' = ' + imgW/imgH);

    if(vpW/vpH < imgW/imgH) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('horizontalbar')[i].style.height = (vpH - vpW)/2 + 'px';
            document.getElementsByClassName('box sidebar')[i].style.width = '0px';
        }
    } else {
        for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('box sidebar')[i].style.width = (vpW - vpH)/2 + 'px';
            document.getElementsByClassName('horizontalbar')[i].style.height = '0px'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Совсем не понятно, что должна делать ваша функция throttle, и в вашем коде ее совсем нет, что именно значат ее аргументы. Опишите подробнее задачу.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin, функция [тормозилка](https://learn.javascript.ru/task/throttle)

Comment: @Sergey Glazirin, при ресайзе функция обновления вызывается каждый раз при мельчайшем изменении, а если я сильно изменяю размер, то это обновление будет вызвано очень много раз, поэтому можно ограничить кол-во вызовов функции updateSize. Но вот как это сделать не пойму. Но уже нашел решение для debounce. Но если я правильно понял теорию про debounce и throttle, мне нужно использовать throttle, чтобы обработать событие, когда я перестал менять размер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что должна делать функция:

```js
const f = (a) => {
  console.log(a)
};

// затормозить функцию до одного раза в 1000 мс
const f1000 = throttle(f, 1000);

f1000(1); // выведет 1
f1000(2); // (тормозим, не прошло 1000 мс)
f1000(3); // (тормозим, не прошло 1000 мс)

// когда пройдёт 1000 мс...
// выведет 3, промежуточное значение 2 игнорируется
```

Как работает функция:

```
const throttle = (func, ms) => {

  let isThrottled = false,
    savedArgs = null,
    savedThis = null;

  function wrapper(...args) {

    if (isThrottled) { // (2)
      savedArgs = args;
      savedThis = this;
      return;
    }

    func.apply(this, args); // (1)
    isThrottled = true;

    setTimeout(function() {
      isThrottled = false; // (3)
      if (savedArgs) {
        wrapper.apply(savedThis, savedArgs);
        savedArgs = savedThis = null;
      }
    }, ms);
  }

  return wrapper;
}
```

Шаги работы этой функции:

1. Декоратор throttle возвращает функцию-обёртку wrapper, которая при первом вызове запускает func и переходит в состояние «паузы» (isThrottled = true).
2. В этом состоянии все новые вызовы запоминаются в замыкании через savedArgs/savedThis. Обратим внимание, что и контекст вызова и аргументы для нас одинаково важны и запоминаются одновременно. Только зная и то и другое, можно воспроизвести вызов правильно.
3. Далее, когда пройдёт таймаут ms миллисекунд – пауза будет снята, а wrapper – запущен с последними аргументами и контекстом (если во время паузы были вызовы).

[(Источник)](https://learn.javascript.ru/task/throttle)

Answer (score 1):

Если throttle реализована правильно, то должно работать. Попробуйте протестировать со throttle из библиотеки [underscore](https://underscorejs.org/#throttle). Пример из документации:

```
var throttled = _.throttle(updatePosition, 100);
$(window).scroll(throttled);
```